# What is wrong with my input file?

Tags: fortran

I am using Fortran 90 code for my research. I have compiled it but when I try to run it

```
 Reading startup model from start.txt...
   Target Misfit:   1.00000000    
   Converged Flag:           0

 Reading data from DATATESTKAREN.txt...
  No number found by rdcode
```

I am giving rdcode

```
! rdcode provides a patch to get around the lack of an internal
! free-format (list-directed) read on some compilers, notably the
! cray.  This version for reals.  Butchered from decode by Bob Parker.
! 
! on input:
!    string = character string containing number to be read
!    iof2 = unit number of open file, to be closed on error 
! on output:
!    rdcode contains a real number from string
! calls:
!    filerr
!
! includes:
      IMPLICIT NONE
! input arguments:
      character(*) string
      integer iof2
! local variables
      character(40) local
      integer k, k1, kn, l
!
!  Terminate line at % sign
      kn=index(string//'%', '%') - 1
      k1=1
      do 1100 k=k1, kn
        if (string(k:k) .ne. ' ') goto 1200
 1100 continue
      call filerr (' No number found by rdcode', iof2)
```

Input file is quite big, I just want to ask how to search for error. As I understand rdocde is converting string to integer?

Comment: Unless you are referring to a particular version of the Fortran Standard, please use the generic [tag:fortran] tag.

Comment: I would assume that the string you provided has zero length or is made up entirely of blanks. It's hard to tell, though, because you do not tell us the string you are passing as an argument...